# ENOTFOUND Package Save Not Found, While Installing Angular Material Icon

Tags: angularjs, bower

I am a beginner in AngularJs & while I am trying to install Angular Material Icon using bower, I am getting **ENOTFOUND** Package save not found Error.
I am using this command
`bower install save angular-material-icons`
These are my dependencies

```
   "dependencies": {
        "angular": "~1.5.8",
        "angular-animate": "~1.5.8",
        "angular-messages": "~1.5.8",
        "angular-touch": "~1.5.8",
        "angular-aria": "~1.5.8",
        "angular-resource": "~1.5.8",
        "angular-material": "^1.1.1",
        "moment": "~2.10.6",
        "angular-sanitize": "~1.5.8",
        "angular-ui-router": "^0.3.1",
        "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^3.0.0",
        "google-open-sans": "^1.0.0",
        "angular-route": "1.5.8",
        "ngstorage": "^0.3.11",
        "smDateTimeRangePicker": "^1.6.1",
        "ng-intl-tel-input": "^2.0.0",
        "angular-youtube-mb": "^1.3.1",
        "leaflet": "^1.0.2",
        "md-data-table": "^2.2.0"
      }
```

Please Suggest If Anyone Faced the similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not bower expert, but I'm pretty sure that you should use `save` parameter this way:

```
bower install angular-material-icons --save
```

Comment: Thanks, This Worked.